# How to update a table using a select group by in a second one and itself as the data source in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1093

I can do this:

```
SELECT t2.value + sum(t3.value)
FROM tableA t2, tableB t3
WHERE t2.somekey = t3.somekey
GROUP BY t3.somekey
```

But how to do this?

```
 UPDATE tableA t1
    SET speed = (
        SELECT t2.value + sum(t3.value)
        FROM tableA t2, tableB t3
        WHERE t2.somekey = t3.somekey
        AND t1.somekey = t3.somekey
        GROUP BY t3.somekey
   )
;
```

MySQL says it's illegal since you can't specify target table `t1` for update in FROM clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by rewriting your query:

```
UPDATE tableA t1, (
   SELECT somekey, SUM(value) value
   FROM tableB t3
   GROUP BY somekey
) t2
SET speed = t1.value + t2.value
WHERE t1.somekey = t2.somekey;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using `MySQL`'s extension to `GROUP BY` which should not be used in this context.

Given the following values:

```
tableA

value somekey
1     1
2     1

tableB

value somekey
3     1
4     1
```

this subquery:

```
    SELECT  t2.value + SUM(t3.value)
    FROM    tableA t2, tableB t3
    WHERE   t2.somekey = t3.somekey
            AND t1.somekey = t3.somekey
    GROUP BY
            t3.somekey
```

will return you either `8` or `9`: it will calculate `SUM(b.value) = 7` and then add a *random* value from `A` for the given key.

For this sample data, which value do you want the speed to be updated to?